# Continuously running loop in ElectronJS/Angularapp without blocking renderer

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an ElectronJS desktop app that's calling a Powershell command on a 5 second interval to get the list of attached removable drives from within the app's "ready" event. It seems this loop (in a setInterval) causes the main BrowserWindow to be ""Not Responding".

The app basically just shows the user their attached removable devices (like USB cards, SD cards, etc) so I have it calling a Powershell command which is straightforward and easy since our users are all corporate and running Windows, but I'm worried about the renderer/browser getting blocked. How can I have this continuously running loop on an interval in ElectronJS's main.js without interfering with UI performance or freezing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using readdir instead of readdirSync to examine the files, and by launching powershell off the main process.  The problem was the readdirSync.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ideal candidate for a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

The Electron docs have a small [write up](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading) on multi-threading.